# Trying to pass a variable to another php page based on the data from checkbox

Tags: php, variables, get

I'm trying to use php with mysql. basically i've an index page where user fills a form and another page where all rows are displayed. i've checkboxes for each row for deleting the selected row/rows. i'm trying to create a new page (namely details) where it shows only the selected row. 
I'm trying to use $_GET but i could not do it. maybe the syntax is wrong. any help is welcome.

here are the relative code parts:

display.php:

```
<?
require_once('auth.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Goruntule</title>

<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
<meta name="FORMATTER" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="checkboxForm">
<?


require "config.php";           // All database details will be included here 

$page_name="display.php";

$start=$_GET['start'];        // To take care global variable if OFF
if(!($start > 0)) {                // This variable is set to zero for the first page
$start = 0;
}

$eu = ($start -0);                
$limit = 10;                                 // No of records to be shown per page.
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 


// WE have to find out the number of records in our table. We will use this to break the pages
$query2=" SELECT * FROM table1  ";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
echo mysql_error();
$nume=mysql_num_rows($result2);
/////// The variable nume above will store the total number of records in the table////

/////////// Now let us print the table headers ////////////////
$bgcolor="#f1f1f1";
echo "<TABLE width=80% align=center  cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0> <tr>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='2'>#</font></td>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='2'>ID</font></td>";
echo "<td  bgcolor='dfdfdf' >&nbsp;<font face='arial,verdana,helvetica' color='#000000' size='2'>Time</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";

////////////// Now let us start executing the query with variables $eu and $limit  set at the top of the page///////////
$query=" SELECT * FROM table1  ORDER BY id DESC limit $eu, $limit ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();

//////////////// Now we will display the returned records in side the rows of the table/////////
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($bgcolor=='#f1f1f1'){$bgcolor='#ffffff';}
else{$bgcolor='#f1f1f1';}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='" . $rows[id] . "'></td>";  
echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='1'>$rows[id]</font></td>"; 
echo "<td align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Verdana' size='1'>$rows[DateTime]</font></td>"; 
echo "<td><a href=\"detail.php?var1=<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>\">Details</a></td>";
//here is the problematic line i guess
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
////////////////////////////// End of displaying the table with records ////////////////////////

///// Variables set for advance paging///////////
$p_limit=100; // This should be more than $limit and set to a value for whick links to be breaked

$p_f=$_GET['p_f'];                // To take care global variable if OFF
if(!($p_f > 0)) {                         // This variable is set to zero for the first page
$p_f = 0;
}



$p_fwd=$p_f+$p_limit;
$p_back=$p_f-$p_limit;
//////////// End of variables for advance paging ///////////////
/////////////// Start the buttom links with Prev and next link with page numbers /////////////////
echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='20%'>";
if($p_f<>0){print "<a href='$page_name?start=$p_back&p_f=$p_back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV $p_limit</font></a>"; }
echo "</td><td  align='left' width='10%'>";
//// if our variable $back is equal to 0 or more then only we will display the link to move back ////////
if($back >=0 and ($back >=$p_f)) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back&p_f=$p_f'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 
//////////////// Let us display the page links at  center. We will not display the current page as a link ///////////
echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
for($i=$p_f;$i < $nume and $i<($p_f+$p_limit);$i=$i+$limit){
if($i <> $eu){
$i2=$i+$p_f;
echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i&p_f=$p_f'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$i</font></a> ";
}
else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$i</font>";}        /// Current page is not displayed as link and given font color red

}


echo "</td><td  align='right' width='10%'>";
///////////// If we are not in the last page then Next link will be displayed. Here we check that /////
if($this1 < $nume and $this1 <($p_f+$p_limit)) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next&p_f=$p_f'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
echo "</td><td  align='right' width='20%'>";
if($p_fwd < $nume){
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$p_fwd&p_f=$p_fwd'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT $p_limit</font></a>"; 
}
echo "</td></tr></table>";


?>
<tr>
<td colspan="14" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
<form>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Previous" ONCLICK="window.location.href='http://......../util'"> 
</FORM></td>
</tr>
<?php

$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
if($_REQUEST['delete']=='Delete'){
foreach($checkbox as $id => $value)
{$sql="DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id='$value'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=display.php\">";
}
}
?>
<a href="detail.php?var1=<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>">details</a>
<?
mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

detail.php

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
$host="localhost";  
$username=""; 
$password=""; 
$db_name=""; 
$tbl_name="table1"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect ". mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot select DB ". mysql_error());

$num=$_GET['var1'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 where id='$num'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="13" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Bölge</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Time</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><? echo $row['13']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><? echo $row['0']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="14" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
<form>
<input type=button value="Close" onClick="javascript:window.close();">
</form> 
</tr>
<?php

$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
if($_REQUEST['delete']=='Delete'){
foreach($checkbox as $key=>$value)
{$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$value'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=display.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<html><head><link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head></html>
```

As I've said, the only problem i'm guessing is with the syntax, or something small as i can echo the row when i gave the var1 a specific id. 
I'm sorry if i'm reposting but i couldn't find an answer. Thanks!

Edit: I'm thinking of deleting checkbox parts and adding gif links in the while loop where users can delete, edit or detailed view of the corresponding row. seems easier i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the details link is within the while block.

```
<?php
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<a href="detail.php?var1='.$rows[id].'">Details</a>';
}
?>
```

Looks like you should not be using double quotes.

```
<? echo "$rows[id]" ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>
```

I also suggest you use 'id' as the name of the get rather than 'var1'. 'var1' does not mean anything whereas 'id' makes more sense.

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>">Details</a>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i've corrected but no difference. doesn't echo anything. url showing http://...../detail.php?var1=

Comment: also i don't understand why it doesn't display the table.

Comment: Hard to tell from your partial code - but make sure that the line is within your while block, looks like it might be outside it.

Comment: Also, looks like your pretty new to this. So keep it simple. Strip out everything but the details link. Make sure that works. Then begin adding the table code back in.

Comment: yeah i'm newb, depending solely on internet tutorials =)

Comment: Hi forsvinne - see my edited answer - paste the while loop in exactly as I've done it... should work fine.

Comment: thanks a lot! works, i'll try to add small gif to make it look fancy.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `$rows` outside your `while`-loop. You have to put the

```
<a href="detail.php?var1=<? echo $rows[id]; ?>">Details</a>
```

inside the while loop.

---

**//EDIT:**

Alright, I've stripped your code to the *very neccessary* according to your problem. So don't just copy/paste the code, it probably won't work. But read it carefully, and I hope you get the idea and see what may be wrong with your code ;)

**display.php**

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
require "config.php";

$page_name="display.php";
$start = (isset($_GET['start']) && $_GET['start'] < 1) ? 0 : $_GET['start'];

$eu = ($start-0);
$limit = 10;

$query="SELECT * FROM table1  ORDER BY id DESC limit $eu, $limit";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();

$i = 0; //counter for the bg-color
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="checkboxForm">
<table width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : 
$bgcolor = $i%2 == 0 ? '#ffffff' : '#f1f1f1';
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        </td>
        <td style="align: left; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor; ?>;" id="title">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>
        </td>
       <td style="align: left; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor; ?>;" id="date">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $rows['DateTime']; ?>
       </td>"; 
       <td>
            <a href="detail.php?var1=<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>">Details</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
</form>
```

**detail.php**

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');

$num= isset($_GET['var1']) ? $_GET['var1'] : '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 where id='$num'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
    <? echo $row['13']; ?>
    <? echo $row['0']; ?>
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
    <button onClick="javascript:window.close();">Close</button>
</table>
</form>
```

And not only for security's sake, you should get more familiar with PHP and some design patterns before publishing your website.

Comment: i've included in the while loop, now every row have seperate details link.
'echo "<td><a href=\"detail.php?var1=<?php echo $rows[id]; ?>\">details</a></td>";'
but again nothing is displayed and the url shows http://........./detail.php?var1=<?php%20echo%20164;%20?>

Comment: ok, it's not going to be that serious of a website by the way, it's not even be on internet, just internal. but anyways, thanks for the effort!